# C++ class generation with pre-processor directives

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am trying to generate a class given below with the help of recursive Macros/ pre-processor directives. I cannot use templates as I am building the type (a class). The macro users must be able to create this class without repeating the variables. I do not want to use containers for the variables as they can have meaningful names.

```
class IInterface;

class XYZ
{
      int Mark1, Mark2, Mark3 /* variables to be passed */;
      int count;
      XYZ(IInterface * I) 
      {
            count = 0;
            // initialization values to be passed
            Mark1 = 10; count++; I -> add(Mark1);
            Mark2 = 20; count++; I -> add(Mark2);
            Mark3 = 30; count++; I -> add(Mark3);

      }
};
```

I am trying to put place holders and then expand them.

```
#define CLASS(_name) class _name {\
    int VARS; \
      int count; \
      _name(IInterface * I) \
      { \
            count = 0; \
            VAR = val; count++; I -> add(VAR); \
      } \
};

#define INIT // expansion code

CLASS(XYZ)
INIT(Mark1, 10) // variables should be sent only once for all the placeholders
INIT(Mark2, 20)
INIT(Mark3, 30)
```

How can I expand `INIT` to replace the placeholders?
I would like to know if this is feasible/ recommended.

Comment: Why would you do this rather than using inheritance?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` or `std::array` or `std::map` ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use the pre-processor to define your own programming language syntax.  Have you considered using a scripting language (e.g. python or perl) to generate source files for you as part of the pre-compile step of your make process?

Comment: The variable names are used as in `XYZ::Mark1` and if i put my varibles in the derived class, i cannot access them in my base class.

Comment: It would be better If doing this is possible with C++ pre processor macros. Please suggest a scripting language to achieve the same.

Comment: I would use a scripting language to be a code generator if you have to do this. You can make running this scripting language a pre-build step. Simple job to do in PERL say.

Comment: I would probably choose Perl as my scripting language for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perhaps the "answer" directly to the question but achieves the same aim.

Macros in general are "evil" but can be useful at times. Here, however, they remain evil as anyone using the class later on will be hard-pressed to work out its actual definition, and errors will be much harder to decipher.

Therefore the recommendation is to use a scripting language as a pre-build step that can read in the configuration of your classes and generate the C++ files from it.

Then users of the classes will see actual C++ headers that look comprehensible.

Perl or Python might be used as the scripting language for this purpose. I would probably choose Perl.
You would then make this a pre-build step.

The generated headers would be the target, the scripted definition which is in a format you decide is the input, and a make script would know therefore if the targets are up-to-date.

For the input (class definition) file, you could use XML or JSON format, both of which give you nested key-value pairs with repeating groups. Whichever you choose has the advantages that

- They are well known formats, understood by developers who may need to read or write them
- There is already code to parse them so you won't need to write an actual parser, instead you'd just use the parsed data to generate your output file.